# How to deploy two applications in a single instance in amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have two applications that are deployed as two separate instances in amazon. I want to make it one by combining the war files of the two application in a single jar file. I tried it but no luck. If anyone can guide me it will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the type of application? Java, PHP etc..

Comment: Is this Elastic Beanstalk or just EC2?

Comment: java applications using Elastic Beanstalk.